# How to stop a float in a div to interact with another float in another div?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for school, but i have a problem with my css code. I want to place the section1 and the section2 underneath the header so that it looks like that :
[WANTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuqBO.jpg)

The problem is that it looks like that (the problem is this enormous gap on the left) :
[REALITY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwS16.png)

I know that the problem comes from the float on the header and nav bar but i don't know how to keep the header look and having the two boxes ("section1" and "section2", grouped as "content").

**The CSS code :**

```
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align:justify;
  text-justify:inter-word;
  
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.header_nav {
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.logo h1 {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  height: 50%;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal
}

.nav-option {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 50;
}

.nav-option:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  border: inset #101010 6px ;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  margin: 1%;
  border-left: solid #101010 10px;
}

.section2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

**The HTML code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Histoire de l'Informatique</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header_nav">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="logo.png">
          <h1> HISTOIRE DE L'INFORMATIQUE </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
          <nav>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Données</a></li>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Algorithmes</a></li>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Langages</a></li>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Machines</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </<div>
    <div class= "content">
      <section class="section1">
        <h1>Données</h1>
       <article>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section class="section2">
       <h1>Algorithmes</h1>
       <article>
       </article>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems to work for me provided `.container` has a `width: 100%` on it.

But for what you want exactly, I would use the following:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly; // google all the different options for this
}

// Get rid of the `float` properties on the sections, you won't need them
```

Below, is your original code in a snippet, and with that width property it's working for me.

But I highly recommend switching to flex box over floats, as it will give you way more control and better results.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align:justify;
  text-justify:inter-word;
  
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.header_nav {
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.logo h1 {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  height: 50%;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal
}

.nav-option {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 50;
}

.nav-option:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  border: inset #101010 6px ;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  margin: 1%;
  border-left: solid #101010 10px;
}

.section2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Histoire de l'Informatique</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header_nav">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="logo.png">
          <h1> HISTOIRE DE L'INFORMATIQUE </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
          <nav>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Données</a></li>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Algorithmes</a></li>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Langages</a></li>
             <li><a href="" class="nav-option">Machines</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "content">
      <section class="section1">
        <h1>Données</h1>
       <article>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section class="section2">
       <h1>Algorithmes</h1>
       <article>
       </article>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```